# Newman requests fail if I do not put delay between the requests

Tags: postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

When I run my collection without having any delay between requests, then the initial few requests pass but after that all the requests fail giving 405 status code. Now when I run the same collection with delay between the requests then all the requests pass.
I am not able to debug why it is happening. Can someone help me out?

Comment: That's a 'Method Not Allowed' error, not sure, without more information how that would be a timing thing.

Comment: Yes, it is "Method Not Allowed" error, but when I delayed my requests then all the requests passed. May be the server is not able to process the requests at the rate at which they were coming and putting the delay solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 405 error indicates a problem with your script and/or your web server. The error means that you are attempting to pass back a file that does not have the necessary permissions on the server to receive Post information from another script.

Is it so severe thing to run tests with 200ms delay? 
But it would be great to see all the entities and parameters of the first reqeust that returns this status code